# Pila's Algorithm for factoring cyclotomics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials

In the famous paper([link](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1990-55-192/S0025-5718-1990-1035941-X/S0025-5718-1990-1035941-X.pdf)) of J.Pila he gave an Algorithm on finding $r^{th}$ root of unity in ${\mathbb{F}_p}^{*}$.

The time complexity of that algorithm is mentioned as $O(\log ^{\Delta}{p})$, where $\Delta$ is dependent only on embedding space of A, the number of equations defining A, addition law and their degrees. Here A refers to an abelian variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

I want to find the dependence of $\Delta$ on $r$, more precisely is it exponential or double exponential (As he claims result for only constant $r's$).

Comment: I don't even remotely know the answer, but I added the (reference-request) tag and upvoted so hopefully the question gets more deserved attention. Also if this question doesn't get an answer after a week you might want to try MathOverflow since the question is about math research.

Comment: I am ignorant about Abelian varieties other than elliptic curves. Surely somebody here (or at MathOverflow) knows how the dimension of the Jacobian variety of a Fermat curve depends on the exponent. The affect of the addition laws may be trickier. I didn't study the article in detail, but as the algorithm seeks to generalize Schoof's algorithm for elliptic curves, may be their affect shows in a way like the degree of the division polynomials in Schoof's algorithm. We can wait for a while, and migrate to MO if nobody can comment.

Comment: I would normally approach the problem of locating an $r$th root of unity in $\Bbb{F}_p$ as follows. Obviously $r\mid p-1$. Consequently $a^{(p-1)/r}$
is of order that is a factor of $r$. We can produce such "candidate roots" in $O(\log p)$ modular multiplications by square-and-multiply. However, unless we know the factorization of $r$, we cannot easily guarantee that a candidate is of the correct order.  In those cases we need something stronger like Pila's algorithm - at least that is my understanding.